# queues in Laravel 5.1 error

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I recently Created a job class by the command php artisan make:job --queued and I dispatched it from the controller and it worked fine , and I deleted it again because I don't need it anymore , and I already did an Event class for sending Emails and it's also queued (and worked fine before creating Job Class) the problem now when I trigger php artisan queue:listen I got this Error

> [InvalidArgumentException] 
>   No handler registered for command [__PHP_Incomplete_Class]

and everything was working fine before I created the job class
So What's the problem ?Help me please
Note:
I use the database queue Driver

Comment: What driver do you use for jobs? Maybe there is still a job in the queue

Comment: I use database driver

Comment: I found in the job table a job registred and it's id is incrementing every second now it's near to 9000 Even I deleted it it comes back again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found it Thank You Sir really it was a pending job So What i did is to download a  package that clears the queues from Github 
https://github.com/morrislaptop/laravel-queue-clear
I hope it helps someone has the same problem